# How I can copy from local file to remote DB in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am a novice in psql and need some help.
How can I load a local CSV to a remote DB?

I am using the following command

```
\COPY test(user_id, product_id, value) 
      FROM '/Users/testuser/test.tsv' WITH DELIMITER '\t' CSV HEADER;
```

but this searches the file on the remote DB while I need to do that on my local PC.

Comment: `\copy` reads a local file (it's a `psql` command and can only be used from inside `psql`). `COPY` however (note the missing `\`) will read the file on the server.

Comment: so there is no way to this? i need to copy the file to the remote server?

Comment: is there any difference in copy and \copy? sorry i am really new in psql only know oracle there i can do this without any problem

Comment: Well the difference is, that one reads the file on the server and the other is reading the file on the client. Obviously reading the file on the server will be faster.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply and could you tell me how i can load a tsv? when i say delimiter '\t' it says  ERROR:  COPY delimiter must be a single one-byte character
\copy: ERROR:  COPY delimiter must be a single one-byte character

Comment: Just enter a tab character.

Comment: @user22149 Use a literal tab or `E'\t'` . But tab should be the default if you don't specify a delim anyway.

Comment: The question is clear, and google brought me here for the same question. I don't know why it was closed.

Answer (score 6):

There are two possibilities here.

1. If you are using psql, then \copy is the correct way to do things as you mention.
2. If you are using a client program you have authored, then you need to

   ```
   COPY FROM STDIN.....
   ```

And then feed the file in (see the [documentation on the COPY command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html).

The COPY command is a slightly strange beast.  It is the one command PostgreSQL currently supports from Quel and so it is both non-standard, and based on something of a different paradigm than the rest of the commands.  For this reason it's important to read the docs relatively carefully on this command.